# jQuery Address changed event

Tags: javascript, jquery, deep-linking, jquery-address

I'm trying my hand at jQuery Address http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

On a click event I set $.address.value(mypath);

This fires off the $.address.change() event.

When I click a link I want the behavior to be slightly different than when this event is fired by clicking the back/forward button or with a bookmark or link.

Is there a way to distinguish between the two events. I've looked at the event object passed to $.address.change() and they seem to be identical in both situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I found the answer. There are two other events, $.address.internalChange(fn) and $.address.externalChange(fn). externalChange event is for the forward/back buttons and links. That is what I needed.